# string in #define macro in cython in notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, cython

I have an iPython notebook and I can specify cython macros fine with something like

```
# distutils: define_macros=NAME=VALUE
```

but now I want to pass `VALUE` as a string `"VALUE"`

```
# distutils: define_macros=NAME="VALUE"
```

It IS passing a string, but it's passing `"__Pyx_L1_"`.

I tried `'"VALUE"'` and `\"VALUE\"` but they give compile errors because `'` is for a character and `\` becomes a "stray".

Comment: To me it looks like a cython-bug (not only Ipython but also usual pyx-files are affected) please report it on https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, so probably for the time being one should use the following work around, using `extra_compile_args`-option of `cython`-magic:

```
%%cython -c=-DNAME="VALUE"
# here code
```

adding `-DNAME="VALUE"` to command line of the compiler and thus defining `NAME`.